# How normal user access to database? I'm making java application

Tags: java, database, server, cloud

I'm making java application which recommend user food menus.
So today I made a cloud database to store food names, user accounts, etc..
But to access to database, It need to be permission using IP.

If user asks pizza picture in app, Database need to give user a picture. But the user don't have access permission(?) to database.

So what I want to know is how normal user who uses just app itself access to database.

Comment: trough rest apy usualy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can either give the app direct access to the database - that would be okay as long as there's public data on it that everyone can see, and you use default ports that are not blocked by companies/providers. Nontheless, on the DB side there should be some anti-hacking measurements installed.
2. The normal way is that you write a server application, either standalone, or wrapped into some application server. This application works like most other web servers do, managing the session, granting selected access to data, so a 'controller' between the data(base) and the view (customer's client)

Comment: Thank you for answer :) Can i ask you an example of server application? I couldn't get what it is exactly

Comment: This is a very basic example of an HTTP Server written in Java, standalone: https://dzone.com/articles/simple-http-server-in-java. This is a basic example of an App inside an AppServer (Java Enterprise Edition aka Jakarta): http://www.mastertheboss.com/javaee/jakarta-ee/jakarta-ee-9-hello-world-example-application. If you're not using Java, you can also use PHP, or node.js, or any other language that creates runnable code and can handle Sockets / Internet communication.